# Math Numerics Sum Matrix - FSharp

Tags: machine-learning, f#, linear-algebra

I'm working with the MathNumerics library and just attempting to sum all items in the matrix.  It appears to not work.  Here is what I've got...It appears to be wanting some type annotations somewhere with the sum.  I tried the below annotations, but it seems to think that float is incompatible...?

```
let SumSquares (theta:Vector<float>) (y:float) (trainingData:Matrix<float>) : CostFunction =
    let m = trainingData.RowCount
    trainingData 
    |> Matrix.mapRows(fun a r -> vector[ square((theta * r) - y) ])
    |> Matrix.sum<float,float>()
```

Comment: Did you mean `vector.[` and `v.[0]`?

Comment: for the v.[0] yes, for the other no.  I am creating a new vector in map.Rows.  For some reason mapRows won't let me convert a row into a single float.  Need to return a 1 size vector.

Comment: Actually in this implementation, I shouldn't need to return the V.  I was summing the columns before and didn't re-modify the code.  Couldn't get column summing to work either :(

Comment: I might not need to sum here now that I think of it, but I still want to know how to do it...

Comment: I'm not really sure what is <float,float>() in your last line. If you need to sum all elements you can just pipe it into `|> Matrix.sum`. For example: `let m = DenseMatrix.randomStandard<float> 3 3` then `Matrix.sum m` or `m |> Matrix.sum`

Comment: gah, I had parenthesis in my solution when I tried that.  dropping the parens fixes it...

Comment: If you have the answer, can you please post it for completeness.